# Action of a map on homology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, group-actions, projective-space, exact-sequence

I'm currently studying algebraic topology from [Hatcher's text](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/AT/AT.pdf), and I came across the following problem from an old qualifying exam:

> The coefficient sequence $0 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{p} \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{r} \mathbb{Z}/p \rightarrow 0$ induces a long exact sequence with boundary map $\overline{\beta}_p:H_k(X;\mathbb{Z}/p) \rightarrow H_{k-1}(X;\mathbb{Z})$. We define $\beta_p = r_{\ast}\overline{\beta}_p:H_k(X;\mathbb{Z}/p) \rightarrow H_{k-1}(X;\mathbb{Z}/p)$. Compute the action of $\beta_2$ on $H_{\ast}(\mathbb{R}P^{\infty};\mathbb{Z}/2)$.

I'm not quite sure how to approach this problem; namely, from my reading of Hatcher's text, I'm not familiar with what's meant by computing the action of a map on the homology groups. Hatcher discusses related ideas such as the action of $\pi_1$ on higher homotopy groups, but how can I compute the action specified in this problem?

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I am also reading hatcher, and I'm not familiar with the term "action of a map on a group" either. Given that it's from an old exam on AT, I think it simply means "compute how elements in $H_k$ are mapped into $H_{k-1}$". If that's the case, then it's just a work of analyzing the exactness, which is probably the point of this question. (I just attempted this problem, so if my guess is correct, then i could perhaps post an answer if necessary.)

Comment: @Kevin.S Aah, I see. I think that must be what they're getting at here; as far as posting an answer, please do! That would be very helpful.

Comment: I edited my answer because i misread the question. I thought that $\beta_2$ was referring to dimension $2$, which is incorrect. The map $\beta_2$ really depends on the parity of $k$, i.e., the dimension of homology groups.

Comment: Some context for where the phrase "action" may come from: the maps $\beta_p$ are called Bockstein operators and they form part of what's called the *Steenrod algebra* of cohomology operations.  The fact that the $\mathbb{F}_p$-cohomology of any space is a module over this algebra is very useful, and it is customary to talk about the "action" of the Steenrod algebra on cohomology when referring to this structure.

Comment: @JHF: there is also an action of the mod $p$ Steenrod algebra on the mod $p$ homology.

Comment: @JHF Thank you for the background! Hatcher's text does talk about the Steenrod algebra (as part of one of the special topics in Chapter 4).

That being said, would you say that the user whose answer is posted below interpreted what this problem is asking correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the exact sequence
\begin{align}\ldots\longrightarrow H_{k}(\Bbb RP^\infty;\Bbb Z)\longrightarrow H_{k}(\Bbb RP^\infty;\Bbb Z/2)\overset{\bar{\beta_2}}{\longrightarrow}H_{k-1}(\Bbb RP^\infty;\Bbb Z)\overset{f}{\longrightarrow}H_{k-1}(\Bbb RP^\infty;\Bbb Z)\\ \overset{r_{\ast}}{\longrightarrow} H_{k-1}(\Bbb RP^\infty;\Bbb Z/2)\longrightarrow \ldots\end{align}
Suppose $k\ge 2$ first.

- If $k$ is even, then $H_{k}(\Bbb RP^\infty;\Bbb Z)\cong 0$ so that $\bar{\beta_2}$ is injective and hence an isomorphism because $H_{k}(\Bbb RP^\infty;\Bbb Z/2)$ and $H_{k-1}(\Bbb RP^\infty;\Bbb Z)$ are both isomorphic to $\Bbb Z/2$, which forces $f$ to be trivial so that $r_*$ is also an isomorphism. Therefore, $\beta_2=r_*\bar{\beta_2}$ is also an isomorphism.
- If $k$ is odd, then $H_{k-1}(\Bbb RP^\infty;\Bbb Z)\cong 0$, which means that $\bar{\beta_2}$ trivial so that $\beta_2=r_*\bar{\beta_2}$ must also be trivial.

Suppose $k=1$, then we are computing the map $\beta_2:H_1(\Bbb RP^\infty;\Bbb Z/2)\to H_0(\Bbb RP^\infty;\Bbb Z/2)$. The long exact sequence for this part looks like the following.
\begin{align}\ldots\longrightarrow H_1(\Bbb RP^\infty;\Bbb Z/2)\overset{\bar{\beta_2}}{\longrightarrow}H_0(\Bbb RP^\infty;\Bbb Z)\overset{f}{\longrightarrow} H_0(\Bbb RP^\infty; \Bbb Z)\overset{r_*}{\longrightarrow}H_0(\Bbb RP^\infty;\Bbb Z/2)\longrightarrow 0\end{align}
Since we have $H_1(\Bbb RP^\infty;\Bbb Z/2)\cong\Bbb Z/2$ and $H_0(\Bbb RP^\infty;\Bbb Z)\cong \Bbb Z$, the map $\bar{\beta_2}$ has to be trivial, and $\beta_2=r_*\bar{\beta_2}$ must also be trivial.

In conclusion, $\beta_2:H_k(\Bbb RP^\infty;\Bbb Z/2)\to H_{k-1}(\Bbb RP^\infty;\Bbb Z/2)$ is an isomorphism for $k$ even and trivial for $k$ odd.

Comment: Thanks for all the effort with the edits!! Very nice.